# How to fix " pip install pygame "?

Tags: python, pip

I don't know how to fix this and i try unpack pygame.zip but it not work hm.... something see this screen shot

[this one cmd pip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6p7Sv.png)

[two in thonny ide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZ5Z1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Python 3.8. Unfortunately [pygame](https://pypi.org/project/pygame/) has not released any packages for python 3.8.

See [here](https://pypi.org/project/pygame/#files) for the complete list of pygame packages and the supported python version.

If you are into `pygame` development i would suggest you to downgrade to python 3.7.

Comment: it's good py 3.7 thx sir

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure that `pygame` doesn't compatible with `python3.8`, maybe you should use another python version instead

Comment: @CodeIt haha, you are fast :)